# VS Code C# formatter on save unexcpected behavior

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, formatting

When I save my code is being refactored to certain style choices.
Which can be nice, however I have no idea where I can control the settings, some of the refactorings are not something I want in my project.

In the example you can see it changes the var to implicit typing, which I do not want.

The braces in the if statement can be nice.

The discards `_` as variable for unassigned variables are also something I definitely not want.

I assume this is coming from my C# extension but if I change the auto format on save to off, it still does this.

See example:

Pre-formatted:

[image]

post formatted:

[image]

Comment: The normal C# extension doesn't do that. Perhaps you have another extension installed

Comment: Having trouble finding the extension that does

Comment: I deleted all my extensions and added them 1 by 1, the first extension, C# itself, immidiately gave me the problem, so it is this extension

Comment: Weird, I'm not near my PC, so I can't test this out.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure why, but unchecking this fixed my problem :
[image]

In the settings I also changed this to false:

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541